# i have to compare a word with a list of word so thats the word already exicts in tht list or not which algorithm should i use

Tags: php, sql

eg i have a list of animal saved and i have to check wheather the given animal is in my database or not

Comment: Share sample data and your desired output, then we would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
in_array ( $animal , $animals );
```

In SQL:

```
SELECT 1 FROM animals WHERE name='whateveranimal';
```